# Extend the core and show the data in every page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, service, extend

Following the guideline, I have

1) Create a service provider

```
class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('template', function ($view) {
            $view->with('series_list', Series::all());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

2) Register provider

```
 App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

3) And echo the variable at the template

```
{!! var_dump($series_list)  !!}
```

The problem is :

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('product/view/{id}', 'ProductController@view');
Route::get('product/detail/{id}', 'ProductController@detail');
Route::get('/page/contact', 'PageController@contact');
```

PageController and HomeController can show the $series_list, but ProductController will return error:

```
Undefined variable: series_list in the template
```

Here is the ProductController:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function view($id = 1)
    {
        return view('product/list');
    }

    public function detail($id = 1)
    {
        return view('product/detail');
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Can you home and product/list views?

Answer (score 5):

Another way, a bit shorter

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // other methods

    public function boot()
    {
        $series = Series::all();
        view()->share('series_list', $series);
    }

    // other methods

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your shared the variable only with view called 'template', and your ProductController uses views 'product/list' and 'product/detail'. If you want to share the data with all views, you can do:

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('series_list', Series::all());
});
```

Or even:

```
view()->share('series_list, Series:all());
```

Otherwise, make the first parameter an array and include all views there:

```
view()->composer(['template', 'product.list'], function ($view) {
    $view->with('series_list', Series::all());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, the weird part is product/list and product/detail is extend the template (same as the contact and home), but only contact and home can get the $series_list variable

Comment: Quick two cents why Your first code section is pure evil: if You have like 20 views, 20 SQL queries will be executed. Fix is to pass `Series::all()` as variable instead of call it 20 times. Code: http://pastebin.com/xLVCPViy

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys out of curiosity, doesn't your solution will fetch results even when we don't need this?

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys Got it! my bad. if we need to send it to each and every view then your solution is the best (Y).

Answer (score 0):

create MainController 
use View::share on MainController:: __constructor method now you can overload and share data only child controller

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use @inject ?
In some cases is not a bad idea to make a global service that can be accessed globally, like stats or any other isolated stuff.

```
@inject('stats','App\Services\Stats') 

{{ $stats->series() }}
```

You just need a global service class to handle what you need to serve/inject globally:

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Series;

class Stats {

    public function series()
    {
        return Series::all();
    }
}
```